# how to use 'bcp' utility to transfer data from table to text file in sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Can anyone know about how to use 'bcp' utility to transfer data from table to text file in sql server 2000

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-use-bcp-in-sql-server/319

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "Select * from test..emp" queryout "c:\dept.txt" -c -T -x'
```